# Retrieving records based on a match in an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table `X` in DynamoDb with data that looks like this:

```
{
    'ID': '5',
    'Parents': [
        {
            'ParentID': '1'
        },
        {
            'ParentID': '2'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a scan that gives me all entities from `X` that has a parent with a particular ID. How can I accomplish this?

A scan like this returns 0 results:

```
const params =
    {
        'TableName': 'X',
        'ScanFilter': {
            'Parents.ParentID': {
                'ComparisonOperator': 'EQ',
                'AttributeValueList': [{ 'S': '1' }]
            },
        },
    };
```

Comment: I don't believe there is anyway to do this because you are using `Map` types inside your `Parents`, and I don't see any way to use `FilterExpression` over attributes like that. One way you could do it (not sure how far along you are) is to make `Parents` a `StringSet` and use a `FilterExpression` like `contains(Parents, :v)` where `":v"` evaluates to the Id you are looking for.

Comment: @mkobit that would be a solution in this contrived example but sadly the objects I have inside `Parents` contain multiple fields so it's not an option (I think).